# TikZ arrow emanating from node at an angle for a distance

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I draw a line of length `l` and at an angle of `a` from a circular node `N` in TikZ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can access the points around a node with `<node name.angle>` for example, `a.50` will give you a point on the border of node `a` at an angle of 50 degrees. Further, you can draw a line of length `l`cm elevated at an angle of `t` degrees by `(t:lcm)`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[draw,circle]  at (0,0) (a) {N};
      %% draw a line of 2cm length from the border of node a at an angle 50. The line is having a slope of tan(50).
      \draw (a.50) -- (50:2cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Putting many lines and some make-up ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[circle]  at (0,0) (a) {N};
      \foreach \angle in {5,10,...,360}{%
      \draw (a.\angle) -- (\angle:2cm);
      }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And some animation:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \foreach \angle in {1,2,...,360}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \path (-2,-2.3) rectangle (2,2.3);  %% pad some bounding box
      \node[circle]  at (0,0) (a) {N};      
      \draw (a.-\angle) -- (-\angle:2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hope I understood the question :-)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly and much more than I was looking for!  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, am I right that to make it relative to the node `a`, you should add `++` in front of the `(50:2cm)`?

Comment: What I mean is that if the node `a` were not at the origin, I think your solution doesn't work anymore?

Comment: @NeilG In that case yes. A single `+` may also be handy.

Comment: What's the difference between `+` and `++`?

Comment: @NeilG: `+` also specifies a relative coordinate, but it does not *update* the current point for subsequent usages of relative coordinates. You can use this notation
to specify numerous points, all relative to the same *initial* point, i.e., (0,0). `++` changes the initial point for subsequent paths in the same `\draw` command.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `pins`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [circle,draw,pin={[pin distance=2cm,pin edge={blue,thick}]330:$P_1$},
                     pin=60:$P_2$] at (0,0) {N};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Pin `P1` represents the default behaviour: gray line of a certain length, while pin `P2` is customized. Length is set with `pin distance`, while `pin edge` lets you define the colour, the thickness, lets you add an arrowhead or even decorate the path (e.g. a snake path). In both cases what precedes the colon `:` is the angle that defines the slope of the line.

[image]